# PHP Default Argument Value

Tags: php, class

I need a PHP function with default argument value , I don't need string value for default argument .

I need call some else functions as default argument value

for example :

```
class main {

    public function get_Date(){

      date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
      return date('Y');

    }

   // My problem is here !

  public function display_Time ($time = $this->get_Date()){

    return $time ;
  }

}
```

I can't transfer `get_Date()` value to `$time` variable as default argument value.

please help ME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class main {

    public function get_Date($tz = 'America/New_York'){

      date_default_timezone_set($tz);
      return date('Y');

    }

  public function display_Time ($time = null){

    return $time ? $time : $this->get_Date();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the right call although it makes no sense

```
$time = $this->get_Date();

 public function display_Time ($time){
    return $time ;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
public function display_Time ($time = null){
  if (null === $time) $time = $this->get_Date();
  return $time ;
}
```